# what does the predict() method do in the lifeline package?

Tags: python, survival, kaplan-meier, lifelines

I see people using lifeline package and they use predict() method after fitting their data into kaplan_meier_fitter().
I'm not quite sure what predict method does? Does it predict the survival probability at each time?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the (poorly named) `predict` method is returning the survival function at specific time(s). I have thought of deprecating that function and suggest people use the (better named) [`survival_function_at_times`](https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fitters/univariate/KaplanMeierFitter.html?highlight=survival_function_at_times#lifelines.fitters.kaplan_meier_fitter.KaplanMeierFitter.survival_function_at_times) method, which does the same thing as `predict`